# Change position on topright in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Drop(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen

        self.image = pygame.image.load('/home/user/Desktop/project_practise/Practise_new_game/images/drop.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
```

Now I have position for drop water on top left.

[image]

Comment: Is the probelm solved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The top right of the screen is `(self.screen.get_width(), 0)`:

```py
self.rect.x = self.screen.get_width() - self.rect.width
self.rect.y = 0
```